# Determining state space for a dynamic linear model

Tags: kalman-filter, linear-dynamical-system

Are there any techniques for determining a good state space to use for a dynamic linear model? I'm trying to model ad-clicks with observed values being whether a user clicked on an ad and I'm curious if there's any literature on this. I currently have about 50 or so features that I could use but I don't see how to go from that to a state space model.